# How to improve InnoDB's SELECT performance while INSERTing

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

We recently switched our tables to use InnoDB (from MyISAM) specifically so we could take advantage of the ability to make updates to our database while still allowing `SELECT` queries to occur (i.e. by not locking the entire table for each `INSERT`)

We have a cycle that runs weekly and `INSERTS` approximately 100 million rows using `"INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..."`

We are fairly pleased with the current update performance of around 2000 insert/updates per second.

However, while this process is running, we have observed that regular queries take very long.

For example, this took about 5 minutes to execute:

```
SELECT itemid FROM items WHERE itemid = 950768
```

(When the `INSERT`s are not happening, the above query takes several milliseconds.)

Is there any way to force `SELECT` queries to take a higher priority? Otherwise, are there any parameters that I could change in the MySQL configuration that would improve the performance?

We would ideally perform these updates when traffic is low, but anything more than a couple seconds *per SELECT query* would seem to defeat the purpose of being able to simultaneously update and read from the database. I am looking for any suggestions.

We are using Amazon's RDS as our MySQL server.

Thanks!

Comment: how big is your buffer pool and how much ram do you have?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am not sure at this time, BUT I think that I solved this. I found that as long as I query on primary keys or indexed columns the results come back near-instantly. And my only real use-case is to query on indexed fields. I will leave the question open as I am curious and would like to learn more, but I think that my immediate concern is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you have already solved this nearly a year later :) but I thought I would chime in.  According to MySQL's documentation on [internal locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html) (as opposed to explicit, user-initiated locking):

> Table updates are given higher priority than table retrievals. Therefore, when a lock is released, the lock is made available to the requests in the write lock queue and then to the requests in the read lock queue. This ensures that updates to a table are not “starved” even if there is heavy SELECT activity for the table. However, if you have many updates for a table, SELECT statements wait until there are no more updates.

So it sounds like your `SELECT` is getting queued up until your inserts/updates finish (or at least there's a pause.)  Information on altering that priority can be found on MySQL's [Table Locking Issues](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-locking.html) page.